# What does {:} in columnview specification mean?

Tags: org-mode, formatting, org-clock-table

A `columnview` `org-columns` specification may look like this:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :id local :format "%70ITEM(Task) %Effort{:} %CLOCKSUM{:}"
#+END:
```

Sometimes you can see variations without the `{:}` part.

What is the function of `{:}`?

Answer (score 1):

`{:}` is used to add to the parent nodes a sum of the times for each of the child nodes in the table for that column.

In column views anything in `{` `}` is to specify the summary type for that column. `:` is specifically for times.  See `SUMMARY-TYPE` in the [column attributes docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-attributes.html#Column-attributes) for more info.